# Chrome cast implementation with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I am trying to implement Chromecast feature in my iOS Swift app, which also has Facebook SDK used. For Facebook SDK I used bridging header. I did following things:

1. I've downloaded Googlecast iOS Sender SDK and I pasted it inside my project's root folder
2. I've set the Other Linker Flags in Build Settings to: -ObjC -lc++
3. I've added the following framework libraries (linked, not embedded): Accelerate.framework AudioToolbox.framework AVFoundation.framework CoreBluetooth.framework CoreGraphics.framework CoreText.framework Foundation.framework MediaAccessibility.framework MediaPlayer.framework MediaToolbox.framework QuartzCore.framework SystemConfiguration.framework UIKit.framework
4. Still under Linked framework libraries I've added GoogleCast.framework clicking on + -> Add Other... ->GoogleCast.framework
5. I've added in the Build Phases of target a new entry in the Copy Bundle Resources section. I selected Add Other GoogleCast.framework -> Resources -> GoogleCastResources.bundle.

Now I am not able to compile my project. It gives error. If I try to import Google cast header file in bridging header, it throws error `Google/GoogleCast.h file not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option would be to use [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) to manage your libraries. It will help you to quickly setup a working project with these dependencies.

In your case, your `PodFile` would be something like:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'google-cast-sdk', '~> 3.1'
  pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.1'
end
```

You can take a look at the [Getting Started](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) of Cocoapods.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You saved my day. I am able import header files. I am using [https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios/blob/master/HelloTextGoogleCastSwift/ViewController.swift ]  for casting. I can find the device(in logs) but device manger object shows nil (line 64)hence when I click on cast icon it says "Please connect to cast device". From same iphone I can cast youtube.

Comment: You're welcome. Since it's not the same issue as your original question (it was about library import), you’d better create a new question. So, it will be easier for us to help you. If your original issue is solved, don't hesitate to mark it as "solved."